# contactlist mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im making a codeigniter webapp where users can add each other in a contactslist.

The table looks like this:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `accepted` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

The **userid** for the user that makes the request to add the contact is always stored in **user_1** column. The other users **userid** is stored in **user_2**. **user_2** then has to accept the request and the 'accepted' column gets updated to **1**.

I want to list all contacts that are accepted (WHERE accepted = 1) in a html table, and the contact requests (accepted = 0) in another. 
My question is: How can i make a mysql query that selects all the rows and just get the userid from the contact? Its a problem since they can be in either **user_1** or **user_2** (Depending on if they requested or accepted).

Should i change the db table in some way to achieve this. Or could i make a query (active rcords preferably) that accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

George

**Update:**

So the final query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.username, contacts.accepted 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN contacts ON users.id = contacts.user_1
WHERE contacts.user_2 = ' . $this->session->userdata('user_id') . '
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.username, contacts.accepted 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN contacts ON users.id = contacts.user_2
WHERE user_1 = ' . $this->session->userdata('user_id')
```

And works exactly as i described :)

Comment: If you are going to print it in two seperate tables anyway, why not just make two different queries? I.E. `SELECT id, user_1 AS user_id, accepted WHERE accepted=1 AND user_2 = XX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UNION` query. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_1 userid FROM user WHERE accepted = 1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT user_2 userid FROM user WHERE accepted = 1
```

About the join, you'd use something like below for each part of the `UNION`

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.userid, users.username, contacts.accepted 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN contacts ON users.userid = contacts.user_1
WHERE contacts.user_2 = ?
```

Comment: This looks like it could be the solution :). Gonna look into this and get back... Thanks

Comment: This was the sollution, now im having trouble joining the users table :/ Thanks a lot for the help :) Ive updated my question.

Comment: Sweet! :) Works perfectly! Thank you so much for the help :) George

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the contactlist be owned by the user?

```
create table Contactlist (
  OwnerID int, -- ID of the owning User
  ContactID int, -- ID of the contact User
  Accepted bool)
-- With composite primary key on OwnerID, ContactID
```

This way the query would be

```
select * from User
  left outer join Contactlist on User.ID = Contactlist.OwnerID
  left outer join User as Contact on Contactlist.ContactID = Contact.ID
```

Sorry... Overthunk the select ;)

```
select * from Contactlist
  inner join User on Contactlist.ContactID = User.ID
  where Contactlist.OwnerID = <the querying users ID>
```

(MSSQL syntax)

Comment: Its owned by both users.Both users should see the other contact in their list.

Comment: Well, no. User1 has his own contact list, and User2 has his own contact list. Else it would just be a phonebook of everyone in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use queries but it will create problems later on I guess as I have also faced this problem before. You can insert new entries in the same table when a user accepts the request and mark the new record as accepted but this time the user_1 becomes user_2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Alias with joins is waht I think you are asking.

Something like.

```
Select c.id, uRequest.UserName, uRequested.UserName From Contacts c 
  inner join Users As uRequest On c.User_1 = uRequest.id
  inner join Users As uRequested On c.User_2 = URequested.id
Where accepted = 1
```

will give you all contacts where the request has been accepted.